# Is it possible to have two g++ executables with shared lib?

Tags: 12.04, g++, apparmor

It might sound weird but I do want to have two g++ executables. One in normal /usr/bin/g++ which is currently working well. The other under /sandbox/g++ that is protected by apparmor. However when I copied g++ (not symlink, the original executable g++-4.6) to /sandbox/g++, it can't execute with following error:

```
g++-4.6: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

How can I set it to use the same path/lib as the normal g++? I searched online the common answer for above error is to reinstall g++ but my g++ is working well, I just want this one to work at the same time.

Thanks for any suggestions!

**Edit :**

After adding a few PATH rules in bashrc, cc1plus is found but all the including files path are messed up. I guess I'll follow the suggestion of building source files locally and see how to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd ~
cp /usr/bin/g++ gx
touch x.cpp
strace ./gx -o x x.cpp 2>xlog
```

It fails with the same error message, and in xlog you can see that g++ expects to find cc1plus in a relative directory `../lib/etc`. This is irrespective of apparmor.

Now, there is probably some configuration setting you can use to make g++ look elsewhere for cc1plus if you care to build it from source yourself, but forebearing that option I would say g++ must be run from its normal, installed directory. g++ *will* run from a copy of itself in its normal directory, renamed of course. I would think you could subject the copy to apparmor, if that fosters your chickens.

Comment: Thanks, after trying to fix it by adding all the PATH rules, I guess I'll just go ahead and install it from fresh.